# Parallel lipo batteries with mcp73831 charger IC

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, parallel, battery-operated, lipo

After reading this very informative [blog about load sharing while charging batteries](http://blog.zakkemble.co.uk/a-lithium-battery-charger-with-load-sharing/), I'm planning on using an MCP73831 in the same configuration as detailed by the blog for use in a project I'm working on.

In my project I have a space of 9.0*18*48mm to fit batteries within, but since that is an odd size and most batteries I've found on alibaba/aliexpress are very flat, I was going to solder [two of these lipo batteries](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/High-Safety-Rechargeable-801745-3-7V_60725860547.html?spm=a2700.7724838.2017115.66.2cf656f6AwwM2A) in parallel and stacked on top of each other to fill in the space and maximize my battery life as much as possible.

Assuming I'm using these two identical, single cell batteries and they will be joined while at the same level of charge, are there any other concerns that I should address? My assumption is that it should be fine, and I can continue to use the given circuit as shown.

Comment: You have selected a battery that has dimensions of 8.0*17*45mm. There is no room for a second battery cell. How do you envision the fit?

Answer (score 1):

I have a Sanyo Li-Ion battery for an old cell phone that has two cells welded in parallel. Yours will be fine.

Comment: This answer requires a qualification. Your battery is made at a factory which makes thousands of cells per week. So they have a pool of batteries to match their charge-discharge characteristics to fairly high degree, which is required for good battery lifetime. The OP doesn't have the luxury to characterize thousands of batteries and select the matching pair. So your answer could be wrong.

Comment: If the Op wishes to test the batteries for matching within 1% capacity , he can .